# What is the value of the standard deviation $\sigma$?

Tags: image-processing, noise, gaussian, random

I am using the following formula to add the additive Gaussian noise.
`noise= (x/255)*(randn(size(image)))`, where `x` is the variable and `randn` is random value generator. Intensity range is $0-255$. But, what is the value of the standard deviation $\sigma$ here? Is it `x` or `(x/255)`?

Answer (score 2):

`randn` gives you Gaussian noise with std. dev. of 1.

`(x/255)*(randn(size(image)))` gives you a noisy image of std. dev. `(x/255)`

Comment: And intensity range of this noise realization is unlikely to be in $[0,255]$, because there will be negative vaules